# How to match regular expression In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string `[FBWS-1] comes first than [FBWS-2]`

In this string, I want to find all occurance of `[FBWS-NUMBER]`

I tried this :

```js
var term = "[FBWS-1] comes first than [FBWS-2]";
    alert(/^([[A-Z]-[0-9]])$/.test(term));
```

I want to get all the `NUMBERS` where `[FBWS-NUMBER]` string is matched.

But no success. I m new to regular expressions.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: @AndrewBone, i tried this as well https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%5B%5B%5D%5BA-Z%5D-%5B0-9%5D%5B%5D%5D%29%24%2F but still not working

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew closing bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [`^([[A-Z]-[0-9]])$`](https://regex101.com/r/m0qzUO/1) matches start of a string (`^`), a `[` or an uppercase ASCII letter (with `[[A-Z]`), `-`, an ASCII digit and a `]` char at the end of the string. So,basically, strings like `[-2]` or `Z-3]`.

You may use

```
/\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g3H3Uq/1).

**NOTE** If you need to "hardcode" `FBWS` (to only match values like `FBWS-123` and not `ABC-3456`), use it instead of `[A-Z]+` in the pattern, `/\[FBWS-[0-9]+]/g`.

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more (due to `+` quantifier) uppercase ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+` -  one or more (due to `+` quantifier) ASCII digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

The `/g` modifier used with `String#match()` returns all found matches.

JS demo:

```js
var term = "[FBWS-1] comes first than [FBWS-2]";
console.log(term.match(/\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+]/g));
```

Comment: Maybe the OP only wants single digit, So maybe drop the `+` quantifier.

Comment: @RavinderSingh I added a note that in case you want to hardcode `FBWS`, you should use it instead of `[A-Z]+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[\w+-\d]
```

```js
var term = "[FBWS-1] comes first than [FBWS-2]";
alert(/[\w+-\d]/.test(term));
```

There are several reasons why your existing regex doesn't work.

- You trying to match the beginning and ending of your string when you
  actually want everything in between, don't use `^$`
- Your only trying to match one alpha character `[A-Z]` you need to make this greedy using the `+`

You can shorten `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` by using the shorthands `\w` and `\d`. The brackets are generally unnecessary.

Note your code only returns a true false value (your using `test`) ATM it's unclear if this is what you want. You may want to use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a global modifier (`//g`) instead of `test` to get a collection.

Comment: `]` is not a special regex metacharacter *outside* of a character class, so no need escaping it. You only need to escape it when it is *inside* a character class.

Comment: It is not a big problem here, but in case you have to use the pattern in an ES6 compliant regex with `u` modifier, it might be a problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `string.match(reg)` to get all matches strings:

```js
var term = "[FBWS-1] comes first than [FBWS-2]";
var reg1 = /\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]\]/g;
var reg2 = /\[FBWS-[0-9]\]/g;
var arr1 = term.match(reg1);
var arr2 = term.match(reg2)

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `/^([[A-Z]-[0-9]])$/` is wrong.

Give this regex a try, `/\[FBWS-\d\]/g`

remove the g if you only want to find 1 match, as g will find all similar matches

Edit: Someone mentioned that you want ["any combination"-"number"], hence if that's what you're looking for then this should work `/\[[A-Z]+-\d\]/`

Comment: IMHO, the `[A-Z]`, the original pattern implies that there can be `ABCD`, too, not only `FBWS`

Comment: I'm presuming the OP wants to match other alpha numeric patterns not just that one

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer, the question says "I want to find all occurrences of [FBWS-NUMBER]" which means he wants to match other numeric patterns

Comment: But this **doesn't** match other alphanumeric patterns @HyyanAboFakher?

Comment: @Liam Sorry meant a numeric pattern

Comment: Hmm, guess the OP needs to be more specific on what he wants as the regex can be too broad or too narrow.

Though if the OP wants ["any combination"-"number"], then this should work `/\[[A-Z]+-\d\]/`